# Get content between html tags using grep

Tags: linux, bash, curl, terminal, grep

I have a html file which I am trying to get data from. The website is this https://www.tv2.no/nyheter. I am trying to get all the news article from the website.

I do this wget -O news.html https://www.tv2.no/nyheter

this creates a local file for me.

Then I am trying to get all the articles having class article--nyheter. I try running this command

> tr '\n' ' ' < news.html | grep -E "^<article
> class="article-nyheter">.*$"

but I did not got any result. The html structure is like this

```
<body>
<div>
    <article class="article column large-4 small-12">
        hello
    </article>
</div>

<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336304/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:51.312%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=354&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=265.5&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t27 tm26">IEA: Mulig å nå 2-gradersmålet om løftene fra Glasgow holdes</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>

<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336420/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:115.452%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=796&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=597&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t26 tm20">Italienske jegere stoppet på vei ut av landet med 2.027 nedfryste
                troster</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>
```

**sample output as both of the below articles contain class name article--nyheter**

```
<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336420/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:115.452%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=796&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=597&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t26 tm20">Italienske jegere stoppet på vei ut av landet med 2.027 nedfryste
                troster</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>


<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336304/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:51.312%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=354&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=265.5&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t27 tm26">IEA: Mulig å nå 2-gradersmålet om løftene fra Glasgow holdes</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>
```

I have to use grep, sed, curl, awk for this. Cannot use any other parser.

So my expected output is to get all the articles tag having a specific class. I want everything inside those article tags.

Comment: please update the question with the expected output; once issue upfront ... the string`article class="article-nyheter"` does not occur anywhere in the sample data provided; I see `article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter"` and `href="/nyheter/14336304/"`, but nothing like what you've said you're looking for

Comment: done, hope that explains better

Comment: not quite; update the question with a new 'code' section that shoes the **exact** output you're looking for, especially in light of the fact that the string you're searching for does not appear anywhere in the sample input

Comment: How about now? I updated code and gave sample output as well

Comment: obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1032785

Comment: the `article` sections in the expected output are in reverse order of how they appear in the sample input ... are you looking for the `article` sections to be sorted in some particular order and if so what are we suppoed to sort on? if there is no sorting requirement it would help if the expected output were updated to match with the sample inputs

Comment: Maybe you can try a different approach, starting with plain text instead of html: `lynx -dump -nolist -width 1024`, followed by your URL, gives a nice list of headlines. Alternatively: `w3m -dump -cols 1000`. You can also use `pandoc` or relevant perl libraries to render the html to text. If you need the tags specifically, look for a real html parser/editor like `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- there is some valid reason why a HTML-centric tool is not being used to parse out the desired sections
- input is formatted as in the question otherwise the proposed `sed` solution will likely not work correctly
- extract the `<article> ... </article>` pairs where the `article class` entry contains the string `article--nyheter`
- OP's expected output has the two `article--nyheter` sections listed in reverse order; for now I'm going to assume that was some sort of typo and that there are no requirements to sort the two sections

One `sed` idea using ranges to to extract the desired data:

```
sed -n '/<article class.*article--nyheter/,/<\/article>/p' news.html
```

This generates:

```
<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336304/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:51.312%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=354&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=265.5&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336482.jpg?imageId=14336482&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=50.993377483444&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=177&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t27 tm26">IEA: Mulig å nå 2-gradersmålet om løftene fra Glasgow holdes</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>
<article class="article column large-4 small-12 article--nyheter">

    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336420/">


        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:115.452%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt=""
                src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAQAAkAAAIKhI+py+0Po5yUFQA7"
                data-src="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398"
                data-srcset="https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=688&height=796&compression=92 2x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=516&height=597&compression=92 1.5x,https://www.cdn.tv2.no/images/14336464.jpg?imageId=14336464&panox=0&panoy=0&panow=100&panoh=100&heighty=0&heightx=0&heightw=100&heighth=100&width=344&height=398&compression=92 1x">


        </figure>


        <div class="article__content">


            <h2 class="article__title t26 tm20">Italienske jegere stoppet på vei ut av landet med 2.027 nedfryste
                troster</h2>



        </div>
    </a>



</article>
```

If the input data is not formatted as presented in the question (eg, carriage returns/linefeeds are missing) then this `sed` solution likely will not work; a more 'robust' parser would need to be built (eg, via `awk`) ...

Comment: Can you also help to select just first three items which matches this search?

Comment: not sure I understand the question ... the input only has two `<article>` sections of interest ... ?? you'll need to explain what you mean by 'first three items'; since this represents a different/new requirement I'd suggest asking a new question ... making sure to provide sample inputs, any (modified) code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by said code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: I only showed two articles here but I do have like 50 plus but after filtering them (the one you showed me, thanks for that) I want to select only top three of them.

Comment: that may be doable with `sed` hold space but I'm just guessing at this point; I'd suggest creating a new question, perhaps reducing the sample inputs to just a few lines for each `<article>` section (start/end tags, something in middle); while I can think of a few ways to do this via `awk`, you'll likely get better inputs from other folks re: a `sed` solution